# How to find a finite-dimensional invariant subspace for a self-adjoint operator?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Given a self adjoint operator $T$ in a separable Hilbert Space $H$ and a vector $v \in H$, how can we find a sequence of finite rank operators, say $\{F_k\}$, such that $H + F_k$ has a finite dimensional reducing subspace $M_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $dist[v, M_k] \rightarrow 0$? (**Edit: Not yet answered**)

This question is from **Banach Algebra Technique in Operator Algebras* written by **Ronald Douglas**, Problem 5.17. Thanks for Martin's remainder, I should state the source of this question:

[image]

This question is for proving that, in a separable Hilbert Space $H$, given a self-adjoint operator $T$ there exists a compact self-adjoint operator $K$ such that $H+K$ has an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors, namely diagonizable. Assume $\{f_i\}_{i \geq 1}$ is a orthonormal basis of $Ker[T]^{\perp}$ and $\{e_j\}_{j \geq 1}$ a orthonormal basis of $Ker[T]$. I have no control on $T f_j$ so can not proceed.

(**Edit:Answered**)In addition to the question above, for a general self-adjoint operator $T$ in a Hilbert Space $K$ (not necessarily separable), is there a sufficient condition (ideally also necessary) for $T$ to has a invariant subspace which is a proper subspace of $Ker[T]^{\perp}$? And is there such a condition for the same $T$ **NOT TO** have a invariant subspace that is a proper subspace of $Ker[T]^{\perp}$ (like $T f_j$ is not perpendicular to any vectors from any basis of $Ker[T]^{\perp})$?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to prove is the Weyl-von Neumann Theorem. I don't think there's a straightforward proof for it.

As for your second question, the necessary and sufficient condition is that $T$ is not rank-one. By the Spectral Theorem, you can see $T$ as a multiplication operator $M_g\in L^2(X)$ for some measure space $X$. If $T$ is not rank-one, then $g$ is not supported on an atom;  letting  $E\subset \{g\ne0\}$ be a proper subset, we get that $1_E\,L^2(X)$ is a proper invariant subspace for $M_g$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forget to include the source of the question and this is indeed Weyl-von Neumann Theorem according to the original text but I believe this question is asking for another way to prove it.

Comment: Could you help clarify what do you mean by "see $T$ as a multiplication operator $M_g \in B[L^2(X)]$"? If I write $T$ in the form $\int \lambda\,P_{\lambda}$ as its spectral decomposition, do you mean $T e_i = P_{\lambda} e_i$ where $P_{\lambda}$ is the projection for $Ker[T - \lambda]$?

Comment: No, I meant [exactly what I said](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Multiplication_operator_version).

Comment: I got it now. It is simply because I do not fully understand the concept....